# Defining different pandas xlsxwriter border types

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I would like to define different strengths for bottom-borders with xlsxwriter. My question is: How can I prevent the thick-bottom-HEADER-border from being overwritten in the example below? 
I would like to note, that if I start one row later with the conditional format, I get one row without bottom borders.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dates = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('2000-01-01', periods = 15), columns = ['date'])
d = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 5, (15, 3)), columns = list('abc'))
d = pd.concat([dates, d], axis = 1)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('dates_border.xlsx',
                    #OR: 'c:\\users\\USER_NAME\\desktop\\dates_border.xlsx',
                    datetime_format='yyyy.mm') 
d.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1', index = False)
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
workbook  = writer.book

# header: I LOSE THE THICK BOTTOM BORDER OF THE HEADER
header_format = workbook.add_format({'bottom': 2, 'bg_color': '#F9DA04'})
for col_num, value in enumerate(d.columns.values):
worksheet.write(0, col_num, value, header_format)

# data with bottom borders
format1 = workbook.add_format()
format1.set_bottom(7)

worksheet.conditional_format(1, 0, d.shape[0], d.shape[1] -1,
{'type': 'cell',
 'criteria': '<>',
 'value': '""',
 'format': format1})

writer.save()
```

Thx & kind regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've provided a workaround below. I added another conditional format for the second row only called 'format2'.  It sets the top of the cells with the thick border and the bottom with the dotted lines.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dates = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('2000-01-01', periods = 15), columns = ['date'])
d = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 5, (15, 3)), columns = list('abc'))
d = pd.concat([dates, d], axis = 1)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('dates_border.xlsx',
                    #OR: 'c:\\users\\USER_NAME\\desktop\\dates_border.xlsx',
                    datetime_format='yyyy.mm') 
d.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1', index = False)
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
workbook  = writer.book

# header: I LOSE THE THICK BOTTOM BORDER OF THE HEADER
header_format = workbook.add_format({'bottom': 2, 'bg_color': '#F9DA04'})
for col_num, value in enumerate(d.columns.values):
    worksheet.write(0, col_num, value, header_format)

# data with bottom borders
format1 = workbook.add_format()
format1.set_bottom(7)

#snippet added to op script
format2 = workbook.add_format()
format2.set_top(2)
format2.set_bottom(7)

worksheet.conditional_format(1, 0, 1, d.shape[1] -1,
{'type': 'cell',
 'criteria': '<>',
 'value': '""',
 'format': format2})
#end of snippet added to op script

worksheet.conditional_format(1, 0, d.shape[0], d.shape[1] -1,
{'type': 'cell',
 'criteria': '<>',
 'value': '""',
 'format': format1})

writer.save()
```

With Expected Output:

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: how to deal if any value in the data frame is null i.e. empty string ?